# Find value nearest to x only if it's less than x

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array of doubles. How can I find the value nearest to some input value without going higher than that input value.

Comment: Nothing yet. I thought of just subtracting each from x and checked which yields the smallest difference, but I assume there's a simpler way.

Comment: What could be simpler than inspecting each element individually?

Comment: What you shouldn't do is sorting the input array while you can calculate it in one pass

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using LINQ in C#

```
// Assuming values is IEnumerable<double>
values = values.Where(v => v <= input);

return values.Any() ? values.Max() : resultWhenInputTooSmall;
```

Comment: I like this one. I'm very new to C#. I've programmed in C++ and Java in great detail. I'll try this one out.

Comment: I would change the second line to `return values.Any() ? ..`

Comment: @BrokenGlass nice, not sure why I never considered using Any() to test for non-emptiness.  Always just assumed it needed a condition.  Updated, thanks!

Comment: Now, 5 years later, I think `return values.Max(x => x <= input);` is a cleaner solution depending what it's expected to do when the condition isn't met.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int checkClosest(int target)
{
    int closestVal = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < thing.length; i++)
        if(thing[i] < target && thing[i] > closestVal) closestVal = thing[i];
    return closestVal;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried your code before posting? It doesn't even compile besides giving wrong result.

Comment: I write things like this all the time. But no. Would you like me to? If it doesn't work, I'm sure you can figure it out anyway.

Comment: Add an `abs()` or `fabs()` or whatever the C# equivalent for absolute-value is, and this looks like the winner. :)

Comment: It's java, by the way. `thing` is your array. Its conditions are if `thing[i]` is less than your target, and it's greater than the closest value it's found so far.

Comment: `I write things like this all the time`. You should work more on this :)

Comment: I changed it. It's odd to get used to; not a key I naturally reach for.

Answer (score -1):

In CSharp , you can use linq to implement it more easier.

```
var result = doubleArray.Where(p => p < inputValue).OrderByDescending(p => p).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score -2):

Sort them first (lots of ways of doing this).  Then do a binary search for the number that you're looking for.

Comment: That's O(N Log N). A simple linear scan is O(N). Sorting only makes sense if there's something else to be done.

Comment: Touche.  That's very true.  But if you do it my way, the code could be shorter and more readable than using a linear scan.  I think I can do it with two lines of Java (and it looks like @Scott has managed it in just one line of C#).  The OP didn't specify whether scalability or readability is more important, so I went for the answer that will end up more readable.

Comment: Heh, I wasn't sure it _was_ going to be more readable until I see the LINQ examples here! [user1131435's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9058389/377270) is the only one I'd feel confident reading on quick glance, and then your hypothetical solution would probably come next. :) Hehe. Like I said, the sort isn't _wrong_, there just better be some other compelling reason to sort to justify the cost...